# Collision of the boxes coming from two different paths

Tags: automation, logic

I am at a customer place and thinking about a logic about the box passing. I am afraid that I have not reached out to an clean solution yet.

Problem statement:

There are two points from where boxes can come on a path. pointA & pointB. All I want is to figure out how to make sure that the boxes do not collide if they come from different paths. Pictorial representation is attached for the problem. I am free to put sensors on the path to know whether box has come or not.

In the image I have attached, there are 3 sensors, s1, s2, s3 which tell me that if there are any boxes in front of them or not. [image]

This is what I have thought of till now. If there is any box in front of s3, stop box at s1 and let box at s3 go. As soon as box at s3 reaches to s2, I start moving box at s1. Please write me if I am not clear on this.

Problem I see is if multiple boxes, say 2 boxes box1 & box2, come together at s3 separated by minor space. In my logic, box1 at s3 would stop the box at s1, which is fine. Along with box1, box2 would also go from s3. Whenever sensor at s2 sees that box1 has reached s2, my logic starts moving box at s1 as well and thus box from s1 and box2 would collide.

How do I make clean logic for this problem so that boxes do not collide.

I know it is difficult to explain. I am very happy to write any clarifications, if needed.

P.S. Tagging C++ since I am coding in C++ for this. Admin, please feel free to add the right tags.

Comment: Do the boxes have a constant speed?

Comment: @jabaa Yes. It has constant speed.

Comment: In that case you only need s3. You know when a box arrives at the sensor and when it leaves. You can calculate when to stop the other box.

Comment: I understand this for single box and can not understand this when there are multiple boxes.

Comment: Let's say the boxes move with 1m/s. Sensor s3 detects a box from 3s to 4s and another box from 5s to 7s. This means that the first box has a length of 1m, the second has a length of 2m and there is 1m distance between the boxes. You can calculate the exact location for each moment.

Comment: @jabaa. Thanks for thinking on it.

However, it is easier than this actually. Even the box sizes are same. I think it might be fair to write something like this:

`if(s3 is on) { start s3, stop s2 }`
`else if (s1 is on) { start s1, stop s3 }`

That should be fine, I guess.

Comment: No, I don't think your approach is reliable. At least, you have to count the boxes that passed s3 and s2, otherwise there can be collisions. Or you need some requirements for the positions of the sensors. What does `start s3` and `stop s2` mean? Why would you start and stop sensors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248099/discussion-between-hemant-bhargava-and-jabaa).